# Fedora29の通信を全てTor経由にしたい

Tags: linux, network, fedora

とある一身上の都合によりFedora(GNOME)の全通信を全てTor経由にせざるを得なくなってきたので、`設定`=>`ネットワーク`=>`ネットワークプロキシ`からTorのSocksホスト(localhost)とポート番号(9050)を入力しましたが、何故かシステム全体ではなくChromeのみTorが適用される結果となりました。

Debian系ディストリの場合はこの設定でシステム全体にTorを適用できたのですが、Fedoraではそれができないのでしょうか？また、どのようにしてシステム全体にTorを適用すれば良いのでしょうか？できればTailsは使いたくないので、あくまでFedoraの中で完結したいです。ご教示いただけると助かります。どうかよろしくおねがいします。

Comment: Chrome(ブラウザ)以外では具体的にどのアプリで設定が適用されない(またはさせたい)のでしょうか。 / ブラウザの場合は「システムのproxy設定に従う」のような項目があることが多いですが、その他のアプリでは個別にproxy設定を行う必要がある可能性があります。

Comment: 把握できているだけでもwgetやcurl、w3mと言ったプログラムがデフォルト設定のままTorを使用できません。また当方恥ずかしながら通信監視の知識に疎く「システムに内在するどれだけのプログラムがTorを経由しているか」については正確に把握できていません。なので上記のプログラムがTorを経由しているか否かについては診断くん( http://taruo.net/e/ )にアクセスして確認しています。ただ、4〜5年前にもUbuntuで全ての通信をTor経由にしていましたが、この時はwget等でアクセスした診断くんの結果を見てもTorを経由していましたし、デスクトップ画面（GNOME）に届くTwitterやYouTubeの通知が明らかに遅れていたり、pipやaptの読み込みが非常にスローだったこともあり「全システムに設定したTorが適用されている」ことが直ぐに解かりました。

Answer (score 2):

コマンドラインから起動するツールに関しては、環境変数`http_proxy`に適切な値を設定しておけばよさそうです。プロトコルによっては`https_proxy`や`ftp_proxy`も必要となるでしょう。

```sh
export http_proxy="http://localhost:9051"
```

上記の設定を`.bashrc`または`/etc/bash.bashrc`辺りに記載しておけばよいでしょう。

GUIツールに関してはデスクトップ環境に依存しそうです。GNOMEの場合には既に設定された手順で問題なさそうです。

参考:
[How to set system proxy in Fedora 17? - Ask  Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/10032/how-to-set-system-proxy-in-fedora-17/?answer=14693#post-id-14693)

Comment: すみません。バイトが忙しくて返信できませんでした。ご教示頂いた通り`.bashrc`と`/etc/bash.bashrc`に例の行を追加し`http(s)_proxy`や`ftp_proxy`等にも代入する形で追加しておきましたが、何故か適用されなかったので、試しに`/etc/profile`に追加してしましたがこちらもダメでした。またこちら(https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35519/how-to-direct-bash-network-request-through-a-socket5-proxy)では`export http_proxy=socks5://localhost:9050`と言った形でsocks5を明示的に指定する方法が紹介されていましたが、上記リンクの回答のコメントにあるように、私の環境では「proxy URL socks5://localhost:9050 を解釈中にエラーが発生しました: `socks5' はサポートされていないスキームです」とエラーが出ました。このような設定はFedoraでは難しいのでしょうか？